# Open source alternatives to Image Processing API and Image CDN

Tags: open-source, image-processing, api

I am working on a production-level software development for implementing Image Scaling and Transcoding . I would like to know are there Open-source alternative to Akamai and imgix for image processing APIs and CDN for images.

I am using a micro-service approach in building my application. The project is based on Spring Boot with Maven build.

For Image Metadata purposes I need an API that gives me results as JSON as I am using JPA/Hibernate to map my Objects to a Relational table(MySQL, Oracle).